# !doctype html ruins my script

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have following code which has to return screen coordinates of given object:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">

<div id="help" style="top:100px;right:100px;height:200px;width:200px;position:fixed;border:1px solid #000"></div>
<div id="what">what</div>
<div style="position:relative;margin-top:10000px;"></div>
<script>

function getoffset(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        yPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        xPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return [xPosition, yPosition];
}

function cl(){
    var help = document.getElementById('help');
    var what = document.getElementById('what');
    var where = getoffset(what);
    help.innerHTML= where;

}
setInterval(function (){cl()},100);
</script>
</body>
```

And it works fine on IE,chrome,opera and ff until I add `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` directive(to force IE to respect div positioning). 
 When I do that this code returns the same values whole the time(only Chrome doing fine). What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: What is the exact doctype declaration you're adding? Also, are there any messages written to the Javascript console?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` directive and there is no error or warning messages

Comment: If adding a doctype breaks your HTML, your HTML was not valid to begin with.

Comment: Can you provide a SSCCE? It sounds like your HTML isn't valid. Maybe you have block elements inside paragraphs or similar?

Comment: Without `<!DOCTYPE HTM>` IE ignores `Position:fixed` of the div.

Comment: Chrome seems unhappy about calling scrollTop on the body element. I'd fix that first.

Comment: The code works OK in Chrome for Mac, but does give this helpful warning: `body.scrollLeft is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollLeft' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollLeft' only if in quirks mode.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using some HTML or javascript which depends on the browser being in [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) to function (IE9+ also has an "IE8 standards mode"). Adding a valid modern doctype makes the browser be in standards/strict mode.

The problem probably is your use of `scrollLeft`/`scrollRight` and `scrollTop`/`clientTop`. They [behave differently in older browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport_desktop.html).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, seems like a good answer to me. Upvoted.

Comment: This is a very non-specific answer and about as good an answer as could be given for a question that consisted solely of the title of this question. This question does not, however, consist solely of it's title, it is gives some pretty specific details about the problem and this answer fails to address them at all.

Comment: The solution is not to fix the HTML to be valid HTML 5 (aside from missing a title element, it is already valid, and the lack of a title couldn't cause the problem described).

Comment: What deprecated things are being used in the question that are causing the problem? Which specification marks them as deprecated? What are their replacements?

Comment: @Quentin I believe `scroll*` and `client*` behave differently in standards and quirks mode, I'm looking up the exact differences

Comment: OK, so the problem is getoffset function. Anybody knows replacment for it which is compliant with the standards.